# What code in test Shapiro Wilka in R

Tags: r

I tried to find a description through a call help(shapiro.test). and searches on the Internet. but to no avail. where can I find the code implemented for this function?

Comment: Just type in the name of the function without the brackets and hit enter, it will show you the source code.

Comment: tried it. did not help